# Search to know the best way to do a " Database on demand " for a personal project

Tags: database, postgresql, kubernetes, networking, devops

For a personal project, I want to make a service that permit me to start a db in one click.
And I don't know how to build something's like that.

I want to have the possibility to select the type of db (Postgres, MySQL...), and the db will be deployed automatically without any configuration from me.

It's exactly what Render did for Postgres DB (https://docs.render.com/databases).

I'm lost on the networking part, my first idea was to deploy the db in my k8s cluster, create a service for it and expose it to internet making a nginx proxy.

Do you have idea on how to that and expose to db to internet and access to it from anywhere without exposing my ip directly (can I use a domain name ? ) ?

Comment: Plenty of postgresql, mysql, redis images out there, ready to run in k8s.